# Python: how to keep only first 50 char of a string

Tags: python, string

I have a string which

```
x = "very_long_string_more_than_50_char_long"
```

I want to keep only first 50 char and delete the rest.
how would i do that?

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
x = x[:50]
```

For details on *slices* like this, refer to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).

Comment: how did you post the answer shorter than 30 chars?%)

Comment: or even just `x[:50]` ... yup, @larsks beat me to it

Comment: @larsks Beat you to simplifying it ;) . Useless you too. Adrien Plisson You too ;)

Comment: @Guard Add `<img/><img/><img/><img/><img/><img/><img/><img/>` to the answer.

Comment: @phihag you can also add `<!-- blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla -->`, which is cleaner.

Answer (score 5):

use the powerful slicing mechanism:

```
x = x[:50]
```

Comment: one question: in slicing if i have x[a,b], does it mean start from a (including a) and end at b(but not include b) ?

Comment: Try it!  `a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and then `print a[1:3]` and see what you get!

Answer (score 3):

You could use **slicing**

```
x = "very_long_string_more_than_50_char_long"
print x[0:50]
```

Comment: what does the o mean in x[0:50]?

Comment: @Sunny It's a zero and specifies the start position. For example, `'very_long_string'[1:4]` is `'ery'`

Comment: thanks, in ur last example the reult would be ''ery_'', right?

Comment: @Sunny Nope, the second number is the position of the first element *not* to include in the result.

Comment: so [a,b] means start from a (including a) and end at b(but not include b)

Comment: @Sunny Yup. Feel free to try it in a Python shell.

Comment: @Sunny: *no*. `obj[a,b]` is completely different from `obj[a:b]`. On Python 2, the former will try to get the item (by \_\_getitem__) `(a, b)`, which on a list will fail, but could be valid on a dict. The latter will try to get the slice (by \_\_getslice__) `slice(a, b)`. Make sure you're getting the terminology right.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> x = "fooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo"
>>> len(x)
70

>>> y = x[:50]

>>> len(y)
50
>>> y
'fooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo'
```

Comment: +1 for `"fooooooooetc"`.  In some small way, that made my morning.  Maybe because it just exactly fits the width of the column?